# Creating dataframe by replicating 2 elements

Tags: r

I am trying to make a dataframe that has 1 column.

Referencing the below example, I want biscuit to appear 5 times and cake to appear 10 times.

The code below doesnt work and only shows both 5 times.

```
 y<-data.frame(Food=rep(c("biscuit", "cake"), each=c(5,10)))
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can re-write this to get the desired result?

Comment: `data.frame(Food = c(rep("biscuit", 5), rep("cake", 10)))` or `data.frame(Food = c(rep("biscuit", 5), rep("cake", 10)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do

```
data.frame(Food = rep(c("biscuit", "cake"), times = c(5, 10)))
```

`times` is default so you can actually omit it.